# Prevent header from being updated after calling reloadData?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a UITableView with a custom header that maintains some state.  When I call reloadData to change/update the data in the UITableView, the header gets reloaded too.  Is there any way to prevent this behavior in order to maintain state in the table's header?

Answer (score 3):

Don't put those states in the header. You've mixing the "view" with "model" in the MVC design.

Anyway, you could reload specific rows with `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Comment: Thanks, I should have just done that to begin with...dumb question, I know.