# iOS refresh Header title

Tags: ios, header, tableview, title, reload

I have a [grouped table with 3 categories and one header above the first one](http://i44.tinypic.com/16lk1uf.png) . I would like that after the user types in his/her name , the header title to update itself with that person's name . I've put the `reloadData` method in  `textFieldShouldReturn` after I dismiss the first responder ( keyboard ) . It does not seem to work though . The header title remains the same .

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0 ) 
    {
        if(title==nil)
            return @"Your name here...";
        else
            return title;
    }
    else return nil;
}
```

`title` is a `NSString` which should contain the text from the title cell.

The following code is from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`....

```
UITextField *txt = [[ UITextField alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,10, 200, 30)];``
    txt.delegate = self;
    [cell addSubview:txt];

    if(indexPath.section==0)
    {
        if([indexPath row] == 0)
        {
            [cell.textLabel setText:@"Name"];
            title = txt.text;

        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you modify your original question to show where / how that `UITextField * txt = ...` initializer is being called?  Right now I suspect you are constantly and repeatedly calling that alloc/init method and therefore your `title` variable is always set to NULL.

Comment: the `reloadData` reloads only the table cells or the whole table including the headers and footers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't make it clear because you did not post enough code from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, but you are likely re-creating a UITextField each and every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called (which is a lot).  This also means you're leaking memory like crazy (and your app would get rejected from being listed on the app store, to boot).

To fix this, create a UITableView cell in your xib file and embed a UITextField into it (connect IBOutlets to both), then return the UITableView cell when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called for the index path where you want the text field to appear.

Alternatively, you can create a UITableView cell programatically (not in a xib), initialize the UITextField as you were doing up there and assign that to a variable in your class.

In any event, you only want to alloc & init a UITextField once and ***only*** once.  If you can do that, you can then call `title = txt.text;` (you should also rename your UITextField to something more intuitive, like `nameLabel`).

[Take a look at this related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409259/having-a-uitextfield-in-a-uitableviewcell) to see how to embed a UITextField inside a UITableViewCell.

Comment: Okay , I understand your suggestions but still , how can I change the header's title while the app is running ? After I insert the name , I would like the header to change it's text...

Comment: Calling `reloadData` should also refresh the header ([this related question seems to indicate that fact](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805326/prevent-header-from-being-updated-after-calling-reloaddata))... so simply call `reloadData` after the name is entered (which you can detect via the text field delegate method [`textFieldDidEndEditing:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing:))